# Appending text to the textArea on mouse drop event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a react component, which should append text on mouse drop event. The text dropped is being replaced after each drop instead of being appended. Why this is happening?

```
import React from "react";
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { useState } from "react";;

const CodeArea = () => {
  const [areaValue, setAreaValue] = useState("default");

  const addText = (item) => setAreaValue(areaValue + item.text);
  const changeHandler = e => setAreaValue(e.target.value);

  const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "block",
    drop: addText,
  }));

  return (
    <textarea
      ref={drop}
      id="myTextArea"
      name="myTextArea"
      rows="25"
      cols="50"
      value={areaValue}        // <-- control input value
      onChange={changeHandler} // <--respond to changes
    />
  );
};

CodeArea.propTypes = {
};

export default CodeArea
```